# Repeated http.get requests after receiving response

Tags: node.js

I'd like to repeat an http get request sequentially (one at a time after each one is complete, not in parallel).

```
async function run_http() {
    ...
    http.get(url, (res) => {
        let body = "";

        res.on("data", (chunk) => {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on("end", async() => {
            await processResponse(body)
            run_http()
        });
    });
    ...
}
run_http()
```

This is my code, it seems to work.
However, by running 'run_http' from inside itself, recursively, am I in danger of an unintential memory leak eventually leading to an OOM crash?  'processResponse' is very large so might not be as clean as I like.
OR, does the first run, just exit out and free everything since there is no await in front of run_http()
Normally (in another language), I'd just put everything in an infinite loop.

Comment: why will it time out?  once I  get the response, I want it to repeat so I really want a loop.  I just was not sure how to implement that without doing this recursion (which  I typically avoid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no memory leak here or stack build up.

The `end` event is asynchronous so the stack from the calling of `run_http()` is already cleaned up.

The previous `http.get()` will be able to garbage collect anything related to it as soon as the `res.on('end', ...)` handler returns.

> does the first run, just exit out and free everything since there is no await in front of run_http()

Yes, once you call `run_http()` inside the `res.on('end', ...)` handler, that function starts the http request and then immediately returns, allowing everything in the previous call to `run_http()` to be garbage collected as nothing in its scope is still active.

---

It might be simpler to just use a promise-version of an http request (or promisify one yourself) and then use a regular loop with `await`:

```
 import got from 'got;'

 const delay = (t) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));

 async run_loop() {
     let more = true;
     while(more) {
          const result = await got(url);
          await processResponse(result);
          // perhaps do something that either does a break;
          // or sets more to false to stop the loop
          await delay(someTimeBeforeNextRequest);
     }
 }
```

Note, you rarely want to hammer some http server as fast as possible with no delay between requests, so I've inserted a delay here between requests.

Comment: ok, that's what I thought.  I'm new to node/js and this async type of language so sometimes it gets confusing between what blocks and what doesnt.  "processResponse" takes like 5min to execute so it has a built-in delay though I should add some logic to ensure some exception doesnt cause it to return too quickly and hammer the server